# Using regular expression to divide two words and capture the first word

Tags: python, regex

following part-of-speech tagged sentence: All/DT animals/NNS are/VBP equal/JJ ,/,
but/CC some/DT animals/NNS are/VBP more/RBR equal/JJ than/IN others/NNS ./.

How to write a regular expression that matches only the words of each word/pos-tag in the sentence.

```
text="""All/DT animals/NNS are/VBP equal/JJ ,/, but/CC some/DT animals/NNS 
are/VBP more/RBR equal/JJ than/IN others/NNS ./."""
tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(text)
pattern="([A-Za-z]+)|[A-Za-z]"
print("Upper case words:")
for tok in tokens:
   if re.search(pattern, tok) is not None:
      print("'{}'".format(tok))
```

Comment: What do you want your regex to match?  capital letter text preceded by `/`? like `DT` `NNS` `VBP` etc?

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: You show some code. What is the problem with it?

Comment: Is there any result you are expecting? Please post it.

Comment: I want my regex to match only words (All, animals , are , equal , etc)

Answer (score 2):

Using `re.findall`

```
import re
print (re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z]+)/[a-zA-Z]+',text))
#['All', 'animals', 'are', 'equal', 'but', 'some', 'animals', 'are', 'more', 'equal', 'than', 'others']
```

Comment: Thanks. but how to match the "." at the end of the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
(\S+)\/\S+\s?
```

Explaination:

`(\S+)` is a capturing group which matches any non-whitespace character 
 
`/` matches the character /
`\S+` matches non-whitespace character, but not captured this time
`\s?` optional space at the end

[Here's a link](https://regex101.com/r/r0JZNJ/2/) to test the regex and get explanation

As @Transhuman suggested use `re.findall` to get all the matches:

```
import re
print (re.findall(r'(\S+)/\S+\s?',text))
```

You can test the python code [here](http://tpcg.io/R1t69m):